# update Evolution mail client

Tags: debian, gnome, evolution

Want to update *Evolution mail client* on Debian Jessie. After refreshing the package list from *Synaptics Package Manager*, it is listing the same old version of *Evolution*. But the latest version is 3.22, [given here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution).
[image]

My sources.list is
[image]

If there is any way to get latest version directly from repositories.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to install the latest version?

Comment: After seeing https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en , I thought for a moment it would be better to get it. Other than that it's working smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific need to upgrade Evolution, I reckon the easiest way to upgrade it in Jessie is to wait for [Stretch](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch) to be released (hopefully in the first half of 2017), and upgrade to that. That will have at least Evolution 3.22.2.

Upgrading Evolution pretty much involves upgrading all of GNOME, which isn't for the faint of heart; you should generally stick to what is provided by your distribution. (Alternatively, if tracking GNOME is really important to you, you could change distributions instead — Fedora is probably the distribution which tracks GNOME most closely.)

Comment: Installing the package from stretch using the `apt-pinning` can be harmful ?

Comment: @GAD3R yes, because it ends up pulling in Stretch's `libstdc++-6` which is a major upgrade (even though the soname didn't change, it involves the [g++ ABI transition from 4 to 5](https://wiki.debian.org/GCC5#libstdc.2B-.2B-_ABI_transition)). It may work but I doubt it's been tested much, and no-one will help if it does break.